# LNK2005 - ATL base class symbols already defined - What is the root cause?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I a noob to Visual C++, but have used C++ before. I've have spent days on this problem so any help really appreciated.

I've inherited a significant VC6 code base that I'm trying to compile and link with a newer compiler. The underlying dll projects are compiling and linking and the exe project is compiling but not linking. I get errors that look like this ...

```
MyBaseLib.lib(MyBaseLib.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall ATL::CWindowImplRoot<class ATL::CWindow>::CWindowImplRoot<class ATL::CWindow>(void)" (??0?$CWindowImplRoot@VCWindow@ATL@@@ATL@@QAE@XZ) already defined in ClassInMyExe.obj
```

I've noticed that there are classes in both the exe and the offending MyBaseLib.dll that use ATL, specifically inheriting from CDialogImpl<..>. I've referenced similar questions but I don't see an answer - I don't think that it's as simple as a class definition mistakenly inserted into a header file.

I get the same error in both a VS2010 and VS2005 environments.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all libraries you use compiled with the same compiler, and with the same c|cpp runtime libraries (/MT or /MD). If there are some old libraries left, this may happen.

Comment: All libraries that I have control over (i.e. built from projects in the solution) are compiled with /MDd.

Comment: in general,this error happens when template class is compiled into different ASM code. Because of error is in constructor, something should be wrong with calling to memory allocation functions, for example calling to different versions of them. So you should also look to your paths, if for example you trying to link library compiled with /mdd with library compiled with /md this error will also appear. is there some warnings like "using of msvcr*.lib" conflicts with other library?"

Answer (score 0):

> I've inherited a significant VC6 code base ...

This can be the cause of the errors.

There are many breaking changes in VC++ 2003/2005/2008. VC 6.0 ATL source codes usually aren't compatible with VC++ 2003 or above.

Take a look at below MSDN pages:

[Breaking Changes in ATL 7.0 and MFC 7.0 Since Visual C++ 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sc4t4k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfatlcompatibilityissues_moduleclasses)

[Changes in the Visual C++ 2005 Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8bt6w34%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)